# FreeMarker Spring MVC issue with import

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have issue when importing files in freemarker. My folder structure looks like this:
[image: File structure]

And in my index I have code like this:

```
<#import "../layouts/standart.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.test>
<div><h1>Hello Dude</h1></div>
</@layout.test>
```

My template looks like this:

```
<#macro test>
<html>
...
</html>
</#macro>
```

Here is part of the exception that I get when I try to access page.

> FreeMarker template error: Error reading imported template
>   ../layouts/standart.ftl The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
>   ---------- ==> #import "../layouts/standart.ftl" as ... [in template "index.ftl" at line 1, column 1] ---------- Java stack trace (for
>   programmers): ---------- freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: [...
>   Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at
>   freemarker.core.LibraryLoad.accept(LibraryLoad.java:118) at
>   What am I doing wrong?
>   Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure where Freemarker will look for templates in your application context xml file. These paths are relative to your application context path. For example

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPaths">
        <list>
            <value>/views/</value>
            <value>/templates/</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```